# Why don't I get an input when I call the function?

Tags: javascript, function, call, reverse

Below is my code. I am trying to reverse a string (e.g. "Hello" --> "olleH"), but I am getting no output. I am using Brackets.

```js
function FirstReverse(str){
var str1 = "";

for(var i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    str1 = str1 + str.charAt(i);
}
    return str1;
    console.log(str1);
};

FirstReverse('Hello');
```

Comment: `return` stops a function's execution. The function does return the reversed string. Either `return` *after* logging, or log the call of `FirstReverse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the returned value for `console.log`.

Inside of the function, any statement after [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is never executed.

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var str1 = "";

    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        str1 = str1 + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return str1;
}

console.log(FirstReverse('Hello'));
```